# What exactly happens with wanted and conflicted units while isolating to target

Tags: systemd, systemd-unit, systemd-boot

Following use case: unit `A` and unit `B` are wanted by target `T`. Unit `A` conflicts `B`. Unit `B` is started before unit `A`. System boots into target `T`.

If I understand the [docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html) correctly, unit `A` will stop unit `B` at the time it is started. I will not prevent unit `B` from beeing started at all. Is my assumption correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question. I wrote a simple test to reflect my situation:

```
# Service B
[Unit]
Description=Hello World Service
#After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo test > /tmp/test && sleep 10"
TimeoutStopSec=30
```

and

```
# Service A
[Unit]
Description=Hello World Service
After=B.service
Conflicts=B.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo test2 > /tmp/test2 && sleep 10"
TimeoutStopSec=30
```

and

```
# target T
[Unit]
Description=Foobar boot target
Wants=A.service B.service
```

In this situation, *service B* will not be activated when starting *target T*